# Get Angular table rows data

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get Angular table rows data. Full page source: https://pastebin.com/JszeSf8q (I had to cut the beginning because it's huge). I have this table:

```
<div class="ag-center-cols-container" ref="eCenterContainer" role="rowgroup" unselectable="on" style="width: 700px; height: 50px;">
   <div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="130" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="138" col-id="accessorialExpectedUOMShortName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 600px;  ">m</div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="131" col-id="operationCodeName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 300px; left: 0px;  ">Accessorial Charge</div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="132" col-id="accessorialExpectedAmount" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 150px; left: 300px;  ">120.00000000</div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="133" col-id="accessorialActualAmount" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 150px; left: 450px;  ">110.00000000</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
WebElement accessorialExpectedUOMShortNameWebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@col-id='accessorialExpectedUOMShortName']"));
        assertEquals(accessorialExpectedUOMShortNameWebElement.getText(), "UOM");

        WebElement operationCodeNameWebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@col-id='operationCodeName']"));
        assertEquals(operationCodeNameWebElement.getText(), "Operation Code");

        WebElement accessorialExpectedAmountWebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@col-id='accessorialExpectedAmount']"));
        assertEquals(accessorialExpectedAmountWebElement.getText(), "Expected");

        WebElement accessorialActualAmountWebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@col-id='accessorialActualAmount']"));
        assertEquals(accessorialActualAmountWebElement.getText(), "Actual");
```

I get the table labels. Do you know how I can get the table row values?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are getting?  I am not sure what "table labels" is referring to

Comment: For example I would like to get the value `120.00000000`

Comment: I realize that, but what value *are* you getting?

Comment: `120.00000000` is present twice in shared HTML, which one you want to extract ? same way UOM is present twice

Comment: with the currant code I get  for example `"Operation Code"`

Comment: Hmm, not sure where that is even coming from as it's not present in the HTML you are showing.  `getText()` should be getting you the text value (120.0000000 in this case) so I am not sure why it wouldn't be

Comment: @cruisepandey my company bans pastebin for some reason so I can't see,  but you are probably right.  The issue is in the full HTML and how the OP is accessing it, not just the snippet he provided.

Comment: @Yeah there are 2 text in full HTML shared by OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div/div"));
    for (WebElement e : tableRows) {
        if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("accessorialExpectedAmount")
                    || e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("accessorialActualAmount")) 
                         System.out.println(e.getText());
            }
        }
```